# Lattice plot with different count of rows

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I would like to create a lattice plot with 4 different panels. In 2 of these panels should be 2 boxes and in the other 2 panels should be 3 boxes. Lattice is automatically plotting an empty row within the first 2 panels (see graphic below). How could I delete this empty row/space, so that in the first 2 panels only line_a and line_b are shown?

Example:

```
library("lattice")

set.seed(123)

N <- 2000
dat_a_b <- data.frame(x = rnorm(N),
                  lines = c(rep("line_a", N / 2), 
                            rep("line_b", N / 2)),
                  head1 = rep(c(rep("head1_a", N / 4),
                                rep("head1_b", N / 4)), 2),
                  head2 = rep(c(rep("head2_a", N / 8),
                                rep("head2_b", N / 8)), 4))

dat_c <- data.frame(x = rnorm(N / 2, 5),
                lines = rep("line_c", N / 2),
                head1 = rep(c(rep("head1_a", N / 8),
                              rep("head1_b", N / 8)), 2),
                head2 = rep("head2_a", N / 2))
dat_all <- rbind(dat_a_b, dat_c)

bwplot(x = lines ~ x | head1 * head2, data = dat_all)
```

Current graph:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: [Here's my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14464595/980833) to a similar question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much @Josh O'Brien, that was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the scale of the y axis to "free":

```
bwplot(x = lines ~ x | head1 * head2, data = dat_all,
       scales = list(y = "free"))
```

[image: scales-free]

Comment: Thank you for the easy solution!